# How to copy list of data from one database to another database without getting key as 0 1 2 3 and so on

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to copy data from one realtime database to another realtime database. but the problem is that whenever i save data to another database it's key is changing into numerical values like 0 1 2 3 and so on.

i want to copy same data with same key into another database please help me out, for more clarification check below given two screenshots.

[image: Origial Data]

[image: Copied data to another database]

---

see here what i did

```
List<CategoryModel> categorymodel = new ArrayList<>();
     DATA_BASE_1.child("Categories").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                 CategoryModel value = dataSnapshot.getValue(CategoryModel.class);
                categorymodel.add(value);
                DATA_BASE_2.child("Categories").setValue(categorymodel).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                 
                    }
                });
              

                 
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

---

PLEASE HELP ME OUT THIS PROBLEM

Answer (score 1):

> Now here it becomes 0 instead of AI & ML

This is happening because you are writing in the database the "categorymodel" object which is of `List<CategoryModel>`. When you do this write operation, your list becomes in the database an array, hence those numbers, 1, 2, 3, which are actually the indexes of the array. What you are looking for, is to perform a write operation into the database using a `Map<String, Object>`, in which the key is a String that holds the value of **AI & ML** and the value is an object of type **CategoryModel**. In this way, you'll achieve the database structure that exists in the **first** shared screenshot. For more info, please see the official documentation for writing data to Firebase:

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#write_data

Comment: I want to achieve database as shown in picture 1. here categoryName itself a key value for me. is there anyway to set value in the database using categoryName?

Comment: Yes, as shown in the **first** picture. Sorry, my bad, I wrote second by mistake. Yes, it is, as explained in my answer above, using a Map<String, Object>. Have you tried it?

Comment: I have never tried Map in my life. i learned from some tutorials but i found all tutorials for single child only, i mean i can only setValue() for one child only but i  have many child(i.e. i have 4 category therefore i have to setValue() 4 child at once)

Comment: then i tried some thing like this but its not working 

`y =categorymodel.size();


for(int x=0;x==y;x++ ){
                    databaseReference.child("Category").child(categorymodel.get(x).getcategoryName()).setValue(categorymodel.get(x));
                }
`

Comment: To solve this, you should **first** learn about [Map interface in Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Once, you know how to populate the Map, simply following the steps in my answer above and pass that Map to the `setValue()` method, right?

Comment: i fixed using for loop

Comment: Yes, using a for loop and a Map, should indeed solve the issue.